# How do I increase the scope of a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code:

```
$('.task-list').each(function(list, response) {
    response = $('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray');
});
console.log(response);
```

The error I'm getting is response is undefined. I tried adjusting line 2 to be `var response` but got the same error.

I'm trying to build an array of data by looping over the items on the page and then submitting a single ajax response to the server to update it.

Comment: What does `.sortable('toArray')` do?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you want the result to be?  How many .task-list elements are there?

Comment: `$( this )` instead of `$( '#' + this.id )` please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want [**$.map**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead:

```
var response = $('.task-list').map(function() {
    return $(this).sortable('toArray');
});

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish, as you're overriding the value of response during each iteration.  This might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
var response = [];
$('.task-list').each(function() {
    response.push($(this).sortable('toArray'));
});
// response will now be an array, where each item is another array from each .task-list
console.log(response);
```

Comment: That's the right answer- you're correct- there were multiple errors, response should not have been a parameter.

Comment: Cool. Also take a look at @IAbstractDownvoteFactor's answer. It will give you the same value in `response` as mine, but is a bit cleaner (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have the right parameters for the `each` delegate, but this is how to get the scope outside:

```
var response;
$('.task-list').each(function(list) {
    response = $('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray');
});
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

Move (or rather, declare) the variable outside the function:

```
var response;
$('.task-list').each(function(list, response) {
    response = $('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray');
});
console.log(response);
```

This second example is closer to what I think you want, but I'm not clear what data you're trying to collect.

```
var response = [];
$('.task-list').each(function() {
    response.push($('#' + this.id). <<some data from this element??>>
});
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Note that `response` is one of the parameter names in his `each` iterator.

Comment: It may be an error in my code on my part- I'm not experienced here. The code suggested in this answer did not work, although no error this time, response was empty when it should have contained something by the console log line.

Comment: true... but that wasn't the question he asked.  This does seem to be the wrong way to go about what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Jeremy - your second example is basically what I posted... (edit: except still broken, since you left the response parameter in).

Comment: ...your point being what, exactly?  I answered the OP question in my first example, and tried to answer the perceived intent in the second.  Are you going to downvote because you want bragging rights?

Comment: @Jeremy - No, my point is that your first answer doesn't work, and your second answer (that I guess you've fixed now) was basically copy/paste from my answer, except with the bug from your first answer reintroduced. Nothing personal and wasn't trying to be confrontational, so sorry if I came across wrong.

Comment: @jmar777: meh.  OK, the point here is that the original question was about "increasing" the variable scope, and the code was provided as context.  My intent was not to rewrite the code and provide a complete solution, as that seems outside the scope of the question; it was to provide an answer in the same context as the question, which it seems clear that I did, as you did the same thing.  It seems to me that the purpose for downvoting is not well understood.

Comment: @Jeremy - trying not to be inflammatory, so please take this an entirely technical critique :p. Even when addressing only the variable scoping aspect of the question, your answer was still incorrect. Technically all you did was introduce a *new* variable, `response`, *outside* the scope of the each iterator. The variable that he wanted to increase scope on, however, was his `response` parameter on the iterator. By leaving that parameter intact, your example contained two distinct `response` variables, with the `response` parameter having the exact same scope as in the OP's original example.